# Rails associtating three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, model-associations

I have the following models in my rails application

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
end
class Group < ApplicationRecord 
end
class Role < ApplicationRecord 
end
```

Every `Group` has_many `User` with different `Role`. For example `Group-1` have `User - A` with `Role - Admin` and `Group-1` have `User - B` with `Role - Member` and `Group-2` have `User - A` with `Role - Member`. Like wise each `Group` have multiple `Users` and every `User` have multiple `Role`.

Please guide What kind of association should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a Tri-related table having a record for every membership of a user and saving that user's role as well.

```
class Trirelation
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class User
  has_many :trirelations
  has_many :groups, through: :trirelations
end

class Group
  has_many :trirelations
  has_many :users, through: :trirelations
end

class Role
  has_many :trirelations
end
```

In case you need to query whether a given user is an admin of a group,

```
@role = Trirelation.find_by(user_id: 1, group_id: 21).role.name
```

Comment: It is working perfectly but can you pls make sure is it correct way to query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use `User.find(1).trirelations.find_by(group_id: 21).role.name`
However, you can also implement the roles by adding it as an enum column of Trirelation model instead of creating it as a different model altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a user belongs to only one group and has only one role.

Associations in model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :users
end
```

Columns that should be added to the models:

user:

```
group_id:integer:index
role_id:integer:index
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Updating the associations based on the comments.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :users
  has_many :roles
end

class User < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :group
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Columns that should be added to the models:

user:

```
group_id:integer:index
```

role:

```
group_id:integer:index
```

To find the group and roles of a user you can use:

```
user = User.last
user.group # Returns group of the user
user.group.roles # Returns roles of the user
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I have made some mistake in my question. The Group has many User and User has many Roles based on the Groups. Please let me know if I were not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Incase, If user belongs to many groups and role belongs to many users, I hope the following associations works fine...

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users

  has_many :group_user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :group_user_roles
end

class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users

  has_many :group_user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :group_user_roles
end

class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
end

class GroupUserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :role
end
```

You need to create one more table(GroupUserRole) to associate multiple users with multiple groups for multiple roles.

Comment: So here do I need to create two table as GroupUser and GroupUserRole?

Comment: if a user can be member of any number of groups - and having different roles for each groups - then yes you should create two different tables to create has_many  through association.

Comment: I am getting confuse what is the use of creating a model GroupUser table?.

Comment: if user can involve in as many groups he wants, and a group can have as many user it needs. it this you required both side has_many association which is possible only with has_many through: only. read more about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association